# Como recoger el dato y enviarlo al método del controlador

Tags: html, spring-mvc

Tengo esta web y tiene un campo para rellenar para buscar por nombre, la idea es que al darle a botón con ese dato que le he metido lo meta en el método del controlador y me redirija a la web.

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>All Clientes</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        </br>  </br>
        <h1 class="text-center header">Lista de clientes</h1>
        <div class="container my-2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div th:switch="${list}" class="container my-5">  
                        <p class="my-5">
                            <a href="crearShow" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fas fa-user-plus ml-2"> Añadir Cliente </i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:location.reload()">Actualizar página</a>
                        </p>
                        <form action="show" method="get">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="inputNombre">Nombre para buscar</label>
                                <input type="text"  required="required" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre">
                            </div>
                            <button type=submit th:value="*{nombre}" name="nombre" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar
                            </button>
                        </form>

                        <p class="my-5">

                        </p>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <h2 th:case="null">No record found !!</h2>
                            <div th:case="*">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Dni</th>
                                            <th>Nombre</th>
                                            <th>Apellido</th>
                                            <th>Fecha Nacimineto</th>                                           
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <th:block th:each="cliente : ${list}">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td th:text="${cliente.dni}"></td>
                                            <td th:text="${cliente.nombre}"></td>
                                            <td th:text="${cliente.apellido}"></td>
                                            <td th:text="${cliente.fNacimiento}"></td>                                         
                                            <td>
                                                <form action="delete" method="post">
                                                    <button type=submit th:value="${cliente.dni}" name="dni" class="btn btn-primary"> 
                                                        <i class="fas fa-user-times ml-2"></i></button>
                                                </form>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </th:block>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Este es el método del controlador al que quiero que vaya.

```
  @GetMapping("/nombre")
@ResponseBody
public String bustarXnombre(@RequestParam(name = "nombre", required = true) String nombre) {
    List<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        listaClientes = sCliente.buscarXNombre(nombre);
    } catch (ExcepcionServicio ex) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Cliente no encontrado");
    }
    return "buscar";
}
```

La idea es que me envíe a la pagina buscar donde ya hago un `foreach` del array y lo muestro.

Comment: En base al encabezado es preferible que agregues la función que hace la petición, porque ahi deben de enviarse los parámetros

Comment: @Charls pero donde y como?